# Java: how to compile a huge behemoth of source code

Tags: java, compilation

I've downloaded a big java program in raw source code. How can I compile it? If I try to compile classes with javac I only get errors.

I guess I have to use eclipse? Can anyone point me to a guide on how to compile such a large project in eclipse?

Comment: It's unlikely that Eclipse could magically compile what javac can't. You need to understand what the errors are, so that they can be fixed. Post the errors here if need be.

Comment: What program is it?  Does it have a build script included?

Comment: What errors do you get when compiling? There are a lot of thing that can be wrong, but probably it is your classpath that is not correct for compiling the specific source.

Comment: Why don't you use a Makefile or build.xml (Ant build script) or maven?

Comment: look for either a pom.xml or a build.xml.. odds are you'll find one of them, which will tell you that the project was built with either maven or ant. If you find it, someone should be able to give you some pointers on how to build.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** As some people pointed out, Eclipse *does not* use the javac compiler. Oh well, we live to learn. That does not change the rest of my answer.

<strike>You have to realize that Eclipse uses `javac` to compile the source code. So, if you can't do it, chances are Eclipse won't do any good either.</strike>

It's highly unlikely that all the files are part of the same package/component. You have to figure out (based on the errors), what is the packages organization and the build order.

However, I would suggest you to look around for a `build.xml` or a `Makefile` somewhere close to the top of the tree. If you fidn the former, you could try using `ant` (automated build tool) with it; if you found the latter, try `make` on it.

Comment: However, the Eclipse bundled compiler is *different* than the javac from the JDK, even if "the same Java version". In some situations this *has lead* to strange compilation-differences although usually an error is just an error or missing dependency :)

Comment: Eclipse does NOT use javac ( http://thecoderlounge.blogspot.com/2010/05/ecj-eclipse-java-compiler.html )

Comment: OR a pom.xml indicating *maven* is the build tool.